# Vaadin DateField saves null value to database

Tags: java, hibernate, binding, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm using VAADIN 8 and struggling with a problem. I've bind all fields on FormLayout and want to save values ​​from these fields in a db. All fields are filled with values. The essence of the problem is that the DateField value is sent as null when the object is saved to the database

The question is why DateFiled has null value and how to win the problem?

VAADIN v.8.6.2

Entity (simplified):

```
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OrderID", nullable = false)
    private Long orderID;

    @Column(name = "Description", nullable = false, length = 1000)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "CreationDate", nullable = false)
    private Date creationDate;

public Long getOrderID() { return orderID; }

public String getDescription() { return description; }

public void setDescription(String description) { this.description = description; }

public Date getCreationDate() { return creationDate; }

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) { this.creationDate = creationDate; }

}
```

OrderService(simplified):

```
public class OrderService {

    private static OrderDao orderService;

    public OrderService() {
        orderService = new OrderDao();
    }

    public void persist(Order entity) {
        orderService.openCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
        orderService.persist(entity);
        orderService.closeCurrentSessionwithTransaction();
    }
}
```

Binding(simplified):

```
Binder<Order> binder = new Binder<>(Order.class);
FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
TextField description = new TextField("Description");
DateField creationDate = new DateField("Creation Date");

private Button save = new Button("Save");
private Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");

HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout();
actions.addComponents(save, cancel);

formLayout.addComponents(clientId, description, creationDate, actions);

creationDate.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

binder.forField(this.clientId)
        .bind(Order::getClientID, Order::setClientID);
binder.forField(this.description)
        .bind(Order::getDescription, Order::setDescription);
binder.forField(this.creationDate)
        .withConverter(new SqlDateToLocalDateConverter())
        .bind(Order::getCreationDate, Order::setCreationDate); //the likely problem

binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

binder.setBean(order);

save.addClickListener(e -> save());
cancel.addClickListener(e -> close());
```

Converter class:

```
import com.vaadin.data.Converter;
import com.vaadin.data.Result;
import com.vaadin.data.ValueContext;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class SqlDateToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Result<java.sql.Date> convertToModel(LocalDate value, ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return Result.ok(null);
        }
        return Result.ok( java.sql.Date.valueOf(value) );
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToPresentation(java.sql.Date value, ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return LocalDate.now();
        }
        return value.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

debug mode indicates that the creationDate field is null:
[image: crationDate_is_null]

stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.haulmont.testtask.model.Order.creationDate
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:359)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.dao.OrderDao.persist(OrderDao.java:67)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.service.OrderService.persist(OrderService.java:18)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.ui.AddOrderModalView.save(AddOrderModalView.java:187)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.ui.AddOrderModalView.lambda$new$61446b05$1(AddOrderModalView.java:111)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: your Converter returns java.sql.Date in convertToModel, but creationDate is of type Date (I assume it is java.utils.Date). Are you sure that you need a custom converter? Have you tried the already existing LocalDateToDateConverter?

Comment: creationDate field is type of java.sql.Date in Order entity

Comment: if I use LocalDateToDateConverter (i.e. `.withConverter(new LocalDateToDateConverter())` ) then i get compile error for setter "Incompatible types: Date is not convertible to Date"

Comment: Okay then it looks fine to me :( last thing I noticed that *could* be the cause is that in your converter class, you use Date with package path 3 times, but one time you do not (`implements Converter<LocalDate, Date>`). Can you try with `implements Converter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date>` ?

Comment: nevermind that cannot be the problem as it would have generated compile error because of incompatible type. Where did you debug? have you tried debugging in the converter to see that it returns an actual date and not null?

Comment: I tried as you advised `implements Converter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date>` and this turned out to be a solution to the problem. @Cashbee, thank you very much. Once again you have rescued me.

Comment: oh, nice! I really didn't think that was it! Summing it up in an answer now. edit: haha too late. edit2: at it again thanks :D

Comment: @Cashbee it's never late ;) Try one more time please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is okay except one little detail in your custom Converter class: there is one incocnsistency with the usage of Date class.

Three times you use java.sql.Date as Identifier of the class, but one time you forgot it (`implements Converter<LocalDate, Date>`) and there it mistakingly took java.utils.Date.

Adding the package path `java.sql.Date` there as well will do the trick

```
import com.vaadin.data.Converter;
import com.vaadin.data.Result;
import com.vaadin.data.ValueContext;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class SqlDateToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date> {

    @Override
    public Result<java.sql.Date> convertToModel(LocalDate value, ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return Result.ok(null);
        }
        return Result.ok( java.sql.Date.valueOf(value) );
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToPresentation(java.sql.Date value, ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return LocalDate.now();
        }
        return value.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm still a little confused why this was even possible. When I try to recreate your converter with the mistake in it, it prominently shows an error in my IDE, and compilation fails.

Comment: That is strange. My IDE didn't show any errors with old version of converter

Comment: Hi @Cashbee, unfortunately the case reproduced. I get the same stacktrace again. But now while debugging I see that the correct value comes to the converter class (! = null, the value is date). However, the `save()` method attempts to save the null value for the `creationDate` field.

`private void save() {
        if (binder.validate().isOk()) {
            orderService.persist(order);
            close();
            changeHandler.onChange();
        }
    }`

Is it possible case that the `DateField` clears the content in itself?

Comment: Oh no! Maybe you need to do this: `orderService.persist(binder.getBean());` It's a bit messy to help you with that using comments only. If my suggestion does not solve it directly, then it would be better to make a new post about this :)

Comment: Sadly but I got the same result. I've created a new discussion about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53762129/vaadin-value-from-datefield-is-null-after-conversion