# Vaadin: value from DateField is null after conversion

Tags: java, hibernate, binding, vaadin, vaadin8

I faced with problem that I'm incapable to save typed date in the `DateField` to the database. I'm using Hibernate as ORM framework and there is Order entity that has `java.sql.Date` fields. But as far as I know DateField works only with LocalDate/LocalDateTime. So then in order to bind those fields I created Converter class. The problem was that the Converter received a null value and that's why I got a stacktrace, but the issue was solved in this thread: [Vaadin DateField saves null value to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738585/vaadin-datefield-saves-null-value-to-database)
Many thanks to @Cashbee.
After the Converter class was fixed, the values were correctly saved to the database. But after a while the case repeated

Currently, when I click on the save() button, then the correct value comes to the Converter: 
[image]

However, after the binding the value is null:
[image]

Could you please help me to find solution

VAADIN v.8.6.2

Entity(simplified):

```
/*imports...*/
import java.sql.Date;

@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "OrderID", nullable = false)
    private Long orderID;

    @Column(name = "CreationDate", nullable = false)
    private Date creationDate;

public Date getCreationDate() { return creationDate; }

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) { this.creationDate = creationDate; }

//... other getters & setters

}
```

Converter:

```
import com.vaadin.data.Converter;
import com.vaadin.data.Result;
import com.vaadin.data.ValueContext;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class SqlDateToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, java.sql.Date> {

    @Override
    public Result<java.sql.Date> convertToModel(LocalDate value, ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return Result.ok(null);
        }
        return Result.ok( java.sql.Date.valueOf(value) );
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToPresentation(java.sql.Date value, ValueContext context) {
        if (value == null) {
            return LocalDate.now();
        }
        return value.toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

Class with bindings(simplified):

```
public class AddOrderModalView extends Window {

    private OrderService orderService = new OrderService();
    private Order order = new Order();
    Binder<Order> binder = new Binder<>(Order.class);

    private ChangeHandler changeHandler = new ChangeHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() { }
    };

    private FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
    private DateField creationDate = new DateField("Creation Date");
    private Button save = new Button("Save");
    private Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");


    public AddOrderModalView() {

        VerticalLayout subContent = new VerticalLayout();
        subContent.setSizeFull();

        HorizontalLayout actions = new HorizontalLayout();
        actions.addComponents(save, cancel);

        creationDate.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        formLayout.addComponents(creationDate, actions);

        subContent.addComponent(formLayout);
        setContent(subContent);

        save.addClickListener(e -> save());
        cancel.addClickListener(e -> close());

        bindingFields();

        setModal(true);
    }

    private void bindingFields() {
        binder.forField(this.creationDate)
                .withConverter(new SqlDateToLocalDateConverter())   //Converter java.sql.Data -> LocalDate and vise versa
                .bind(Order::getCreationDate, Order::setCreationDate);

        // ...other fields

       //binder.bindInstanceFields(this);

       binder.setBean(order);
    }

    public interface ChangeHandler { void onChange(); }


    private void save() {
        if (binder.validate().isOk()) {
            orderService.persist(order);
            close();
            changeHandler.onChange();
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.haulmont.testtask.model.Order.creationDate
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:359)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:292)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:200)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.dao.OrderDao.persist(OrderDao.java:67)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.service.OrderService.persist(OrderService.java:18)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.ui.AddOrderModalView.save(AddOrderModalView.java:189)
        at com.haulmont.testtask.ui.AddOrderModalView.lambda$new$61446b05$1(AddOrderModalView.java:113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:499)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:273)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:237)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1014)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:384)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:155)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:116)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:445)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:410)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:274)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1601)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:445)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:225)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You checked that the correct value **comes** to the converter, but have you also checked that the correct sql Date value *is returned by* the converter? I don't think that this is the cause though and the issue will probably be somewhere in the binding of the DateField. I am not accustomed to the `binder.bindInstanceFields(this);` method, maybe try doing this before defining any custom bindings like creationDate, right at the start of `bindingFields()`, because it could be overwriting any prevously made custom bindings

Comment: If we are talking about `convertToModel()` method then the value is correct. Regarding `convertToPresentation()`  when I open window then the method receives null. But then it returns LocalDate.now() which I can see in the field. Don't know if this is the reason. When I put `binder.bindInstanceFields()` at the beginning of the bindingFields() method I received the following exception: `Property type 'java.sql.Date' doesn't match the field type 'java.time.LocalDate'` Btw, I decided to get rid of it because propably it overwrites existing bindings: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/8858

Comment: you probably want to return null if value is null in the `convertToPresentation()`, so the initial value of the DateField is not `now()` but instead empty. But that is not likely to solve the problem that you have. Can you debug your order at a time where you have already (manually) set a creationDate? I mean not *directly* after you set the value but some time after, for example in a button clicklistener that you can invoke afterwards. edit: nvm that is exactly what you already did.. hmm

Comment: debug the `convertToModel()` again and see what happens **after** the return. Is creationDate being set correctly at some point? or does it stay null at all times?

Comment: When I went through the call chain  it was detected that during the execution of `Binder.doConversion()`  my bean with creationDate == null appeared in the debug output. I don’t know if this can be the cause, but there is a suspicion that the bug is in the date format, i.e. the Converter gets value `2018-12-14` and transmits further along the call chain. Perhaps there should be date-time format, for example `2018-12-14 00:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have recreated your setup with only minor differences (using Vaadin 8.4.3 and no attempt to save to DB) and for me it works.

However, I do have an idea where your problem is:

In your Converter method `convertToPresentation()`, you return `LocalDate.now()` if the `java.sql.Date` value is `null`.
**This will show the value of today in the `DateField`, although the value of `order.creationDate` is still `null`**.

The error would only come up if you never manually changed the value of `creationDate` via the DateField. As soon as you set a new Value there, your `order.creationDate` value will be updated successfully and no longer be null.

To prevent this from happening, please change the return value of `convertToPresentation()` to `null` if the value is `null`.

```
@Override
public LocalDate convertToPresentation(java.sql.Date value, ValueContext context) {
    if (value == null) {
        //return LocalDate.now();
        return null;
    }
    return value.toLocalDate();
}
```

If you want the `creationDate` value to be set initially to today, you can do that in your bindings view before calling `binder.setBean(order);`

```
order.setCreationDate(new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());); //not sure how, I just googled it
binder.setBean(order);
```

Comment: Wow, that's awesome! I followed your advice and return null instead of `LocalDate.now()` and it works for me now! Date is stored in the database.
@Cashbee, once again thank you very much. I owe you big time

Comment: so in hindsight, the fact that `it worked for a while and then suddenly it started to throw errors again` will probably be due to the fact that at the beginning, you changed the value manually before saving. Over time, you stopped changing it and tried to save initial value which you thought was 'today' but actually it was still null.

Comment: Also, I always thought you changed the value manually since you debugged the converter methods. While in fact you probably only debugged it at creationtime of the view, and not when changing the value. I have seen the "wrong return" in the converter before and mentioned it in a comment, but immediately turned that idea down because of my assumptions. So in the future, be as clear and detailed as possible when describing what you did ;)

Comment: My case was: I filled in mandatory fields include creationDate and before clicking save I started debug mode. Values in `creationDate` I filled in three ways: 1) chose a date in calendar 2) Typed date-time manually or just change time in the field 3) And as you mentioned I stopped changing anything because I thought `LocalDate.now()` in `convertToPresentation()` method was value by default. I should have described the cases in more detail. But lesson learnt ;)